# c# constructor chaining/default constructor

Tags: c#, class, constructor, chaining

New to programming and was wondering if it is best practice to declare a default constructor in C# in  your code even though I think that C# will do it for you. For instance what is the purpose of the following open constructor with no statements.
The following example is something that I am following along with but don't really understand why the two constructor classes of OperationResult are chained? Why is the empty one even needed?

```
public class OperationResult<T>
{
    public OperationResult()
    {
    }

    public OperationResult(T result, string message) : this()
    {
        this.Result = result;
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public T Result { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: C# will only do it for you if you don't declare any other constructors.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't declare any constructors C# will assume the default constructor with no arguments. So if you don't need any overloads for the constructor and also don't need to write code when new instance of the class is created, you don't need to declare a constructor. However if you have overloads for the constructor (if you declare a constructor with arguments) the constructor with no arguments will not be available unless you explicitly declare it. And in case you don't need any code inside it, it would be like the empty constructor you mentioned in your example.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you don't need to chain them. However, you would need to use a parameterless constructor if you want to use an object initializer:

```cs
var result = new OperationResult {Message = "Hello world"};
```

It is also useful when you have public `set` properties.

Chaining constructors are useful when you have logic that will be repeated at constructors, or when you have base initializations.

For example, consider, that we have the following:

```cs
public sealed class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
         Tags = new List<string>();
    }

    public MyClass(string username) : this()
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(username));

        Username = username;
    }

    public string Username {get; set;}
   
    public List<string> Tags {get;set;}
}
```

Here we have a list identified as `Tags`, and it is initialized with a constructor that has no parameters.

If we call `MyClass(string username)` without including `: this()`, then the base constructor will not be triggered, and the list identified as `Tags` will be initialized with the default value `null`.

If we attempted to perform some kind of action to the `Tags`, an exception would be thrown such as, `NullReferenceException`.

For example, what if we wanted to perform an action such as get by index or call LINQ method, etc? Any type may be assumed since `List<string>` has not been initialized.

With that in mind, some third-party libraries require parameterless constructors.

For example, let's explore Newtonsoft Json. If we do not provide a parameterless constructor, and a constructor with the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute, deserialization will throw an error.

I am unsure if this is the case with the Entity Framework, but usually, if you need a parameterless constructor solely for that purpose then you will set it `private`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need actually of declaring two constructors until & unless you want to use it for specific purpose. If you want to initialise all variables to some value you can write that in constructor.

Ex.

```cs
MyClass
{
    int sum;
    public MyClass()
    {
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

**Now when to use parameterised constructor?**

Let's say you want to initialise the Object with some specified configuration, or let's say you want to use dependency injection with constructor.